# Multiple select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery code that works in this way:

When the page is loaded, it is presents only one  field.

Selecting an option from that field, a new  field is opened and the option have to be all the option of the first  , except the option selected. And so on, also for the other  created.

The jsfiddle is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Joseph82/gVSLZ/)

```
var globalObj = {}; 
var selectedObj = {}; 
var unselectedObj = {};
var currentSelection = "";

function deleteByVal(obj,val) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] == val) delete obj[key];
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'target', function(){
      var curSelected = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    });

    $("#select1").one('click',function(){
      $(this).children().each(function () {
        globalObj[this.value] = this.innerHTML;
    });
      unselectedObj = globalObj;
      });

    $(document).on('change', '.prova > .target', function () {
        $('div').removeClass('prova');

        var $mySelect = $('<select>', {
            class: 'target'
        });

    var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").text();

    var found = 0;
    $.each(selectedObj, function (val, text) {

            if (val === selectedValue) {
          found++; 
        }
        });
    if (found===0) {
      selectedObj[this.value] = selectedValue;
      deleteByVal(unselectedObj,selectedValue);
    }

        console.log(selectedValue);
    console.log(selectedObj);
    console.log(unselectedObj);

    var obj = {}; //create an object
    $(this).children().each(function () {
      if (this.innerHTML!=selectedValue) {
        //code
        obj[this.value] = this.innerHTML;
    }
    });
    console.log("Questo rappresenta obj:");
    console.log(obj);
    console.log("stampa obj conclusa");


    $( "select" ).not(this).each(function( index ) {
          var temp = {}; //create an object
        $(this).children().each(function () {
          if (this.innerHTML === selectedValue) {
        console.log("eliminazione");
        $(this).remove();
          }
        });

      $this = $(this);
      console.log("stampa temp");
      console.log(temp);
      console.log("fine stampa temp");
    });


        $.each(unselectedObj, function (val, text) {
            $mySelect.append($('<option />', {
                value: val,
                text: text
            }));
        });



        var $input = $('<input>', {
            type: 'number',
            style: 'width: 35px',
            min: '1',
            max: '99',
            value: '1'
        });

        var $button = $('<button>', {
            type: 'button',
            class: 'remove_item',
            text: 'delete'
        });

        $(this).parent().after($('<br>', {
            class: 'acapo'
        }), $('<div>', {
            class: 'prova'
        }).append($mySelect, $input, $button));

    $(this).unbind('change');
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).on('click', function(){
      currentSelection  = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    });
    $(this).on('change',function(){

      console.log("nuovo bind");
      var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").text();
      if (currentSelection !== selectedValue) {
          console.log(currentSelection + " to "+ selectedValue);

            $( "select" ).not(this).each(function( index ) {
      $(this).append($('<option />', {
                value: currentSelection,
                text: currentSelection
        }));

        $(this).children().each(function () {
          if (this.innerHTML === selectedValue) {
        console.log("eliminazione");
        $(this).remove();

          }
        });

    });


      }
    });


    });
});
```

The code has some problems and I was thinking to use an existing plugin instead of that code. Is there anyone that knows a plug-in which makes that work?

Comment: Unless this is inside a closure, all objects are global here. Just something to consider. Somebody maintaining this code might think globalObj is the only global object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using javascript templating. I'm declaring my available options at the top in an array, thus separating my data model from the UI. I'm using the handlebars library to then compile a template and append it into the DOM. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LNP8d/1/

HTML/Handlebars

```
<script id="select-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
    <select class="target" id ="select-{{id}}">
        <option value="">Select an option…</option>
        {{#each options}}
            {{#unless selected}}
                <option data-option-key="{{@key}}" value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
            {{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    </select>
    <input type="number" style="width: 35px" min="1" max="99" value="1">
    </div>
</script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//Declare the available options
var options = {
    option1: {
        value: 1,
        label: "Option 1"
    },
    option2: {
        value: 2,
        label: "Option 2"
    },
    option3: {
        value: 3,
        label: "Option 3"
    },
    option4: {
        value: 4,
        label: "Option 4"
    },
}
source      = $("#select-template").html(),
template    = Handlebars.compile(source),
onScreen    = 0;

//Adds another select menu
var showSelect = function(){
   onScreen++;
   $("#container").append(template({id:onScreen, options:options}))
};

//Listens to change events
$("body").on("change", ".target", function(){
    options[$(this).find(":selected").data("option-key")].selected = true;
    showSelect();
});

//Initialises the UI
showSelect();
```

Please note: this is not a complete example. If you decide to use this method, you'll need to add some checks for what happens when the options run out and if someone changes an option. I hope it's successful in showing you an alternative a potentially more flexible method though.

Comment: The previous <select> in your example ramain the same. Insted I need to remove the option that are selected, in order to avoid the selection of the same option in two or more different select field. Moreover, only when the last select is "change" a new select field should be created

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/